# Summarizing prices in sql date ranges

Tags: t-sql, date, common-table-expression, date-range

I have a sql table that looks like this

```
PricelistID periodID   periodstart        periodend         price
1           1          2011/05/01         2011/05/31        50
1           2          2011/06/01         2011/06/30        70
1           3          2011/07/15         2011/07/31        80
2           4          2011/05/01         2011/05/31        100
2           5          2011/06/01         2011/06/30        110
2           6          2011/07/01         2011/07/31        120
```

As shown above, I have defined periods and corresponding daily prices for each day inside a period (periodstart included, periodend included).

Now I would like to find a total price for a period 2011/05/20 (included) - 2011/05/27 (excluded)

Two statements have to be fulfilled

a) If there is a gap between periodend!! and periodstart!! for a search period 2011/05/20 - 2011/05/27, no results should be returned. Or stated differently each day inside a period 2011/05/20 - 2011/05/27 should be inside one or many date ranges periodstart - peroidend defined in sql table

b) No loops

The result set should look like

```
PricelistID   total

    1             350
    2             700
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works.

You only have to create a recursive CTE for the dates and you are home...

```
declare @startDate date = '2011-05-20'
        ,@endDate date = '2011-05-27'

;with testData(PricelistID,periodID,periodstart,periodend,price)
as
(
select 1, 1, cast('2011/05/01' as date), cast('2011/05/31' as date), 50
union all
select 1, 2, cast('2011/06/01' as date), cast('2011/06/30' as date), 70
union all
select 1, 3, cast('2011/07/15' as date), cast('2011/07/31' as date), 80
union all
select 2, 4, cast('2011/05/01' as date), cast('2011/05/31' as date), 100
union all
select 2, 5, cast('2011/06/01' as date), cast('2011/06/30' as date), 110
union all
select 2, 6, cast('2011/07/01' as date), cast('2011/07/31' as date), 120
)
,dates(d)
as
(
select @startDate
union all
select  dateadd(day, 1, d)
from    dates
where   d < dateadd(day, -1, @endDate)
)
select  td.pricelistid
        ,sum(td.price) as total
from    testData td
join    dates
    on  dates.d >= td.periodstart
    and dates.d <= td.periodend
group by
    td.pricelistid
```

Comment: looks good with cte, but this code does not solve the problem with date gaps. try '2011/06/25' - '2011/07/05'. It shouldnt return data, because there is a period missing  2011-07-01 - 2011-07-14.

Comment: Oh, I didnt noticed the gap. However, I guess it could be solved by comparing `COUNT(*)` from the CTE with `COUNT(*)` from the select. And put that in a `CASE`-statement around the `SUM`.

Answer (score 1):

With only one loop:

```
-- tables
create table #prices (
PricelistID int,
periodID   int,
periodstart        datetime,
periodend         datetime,
price int)


create table #interval_price (
PricelistID int,
price int,
period datetime
)

create table #test_gaps (
PricelistID int,
times int
)


-- inserts
insert into #prices values (1,1,convert(datetime, '2011/05/01', 111), convert(datetime, '2011/05/31', 111),50)
insert into #prices values (1,2,convert(datetime, '2011/06/01', 111), convert(datetime, '2011/06/30', 111),70)
insert into #prices values (1,3,convert(datetime, '2011/07/15', 111), convert(datetime, '2011/07/31', 111),80)
insert into #prices values (2,4,convert(datetime, '2011/05/01', 111), convert(datetime, '2011/05/31', 111),100)
insert into #prices values (2,5,convert(datetime, '2011/06/01', 111), convert(datetime, '2011/06/30', 111),110)
insert into #prices values (2,6,convert(datetime, '2011/07/01', 111), convert(datetime, '2011/07/31', 111),120)


-- variables
declare @periodStart datetime, @periodEnd datetime
select @periodStart = convert(datetime, '20110520', 112)
select @periodEnd = convert(datetime, '20110527', 112)



declare @period datetime
select @period = @periodStart

declare @price int, @PriceListID int



while (@period < @periodEnd)
begin   
   select @price = NULL, @PriceListID = NULL

   insert into #interval_price select PricelistID, price, @period from #prices where @period >= periodstart and @period < periodend

   select @period = dateadd(dd, 1, @period)
end

insert into #test_gaps select PriceListID, count(price) from #interval_price group by PricelistID



if (select count(distinct times) from #test_gaps) = 1
begin
  if (select distinct times from #test_gaps) = (select datediff(dd,@periodStart , @periodEnd ))
    begin
      select PriceListID, sum(price) [total] from #interval_price group by PricelistID
    end
end

drop table #prices
drop table #interval_price
```

Comment: thanks, but I think loops would drastically decrease performance on large amount of periods.

Comment: @John test it! I've added the test_gaps part that you refered.